# Impact of restarting nova compute service

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am looking for some guidance related to the following question:

`What will be the impact on the running VMs if nova compute service is restarted?`

Openstack version: Newton

I understand that new connections will probably be affected as the nova-compute api will be unavailable for a few seconds. But will there be any risk to the running VMs ? 
Found few articles like [this](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/92365/nova-service-list-shows-that-all-compute-node-are-down/) but the answers are pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, restarting the compute service on a hypervisor will have no impact on running VMs. They will continue running and keep their connections alive. It can be considered as a "safe" operation.

However, actions such rebuild, delete, reboot, etc. will fail as long as the service is down. In addition, note that restarting the hypervisor itself (`qemu` or `kvm` , for instance) would have impact in the running VMs.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I agree with you too. Could you point to some documentation/evidence which discusses this statement?